# How to sort Excel data on multiple columns

Tags: microsoft-excel, sorting

I would like to have an Ascending sort on a column, but subsetted based on the value in another column. So for example, in column A I have 25 rows equal to 1, followed by 25 rows, equal to 2, followed by 25 rows equal to 3 and so on. Column D has either a 17 in it representing 2017 or a 16 in it representing 2016. I would like to put an ascending sort on D so that all the 2016 data is grouped, followed by the 2017 data, but only while whatever is in column A is the same. So while column A is 1, column D has several rows with a 16, followed by several rows with a 17. Once column A's value changes to 2, column D's filter would start again with 16's followed by 17's. I couldn't find a way with autofilter to apply it within a repeating cycle.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you're referring to Sort and not to Filter. The confusion may be that sorting is possible via the Autofilter (the drop-downs at the top of each column).

There are two good ways to achieve multiple column sorts. The first is much easier to understand:

1. Go to Data>Sort & Filter>Sort then configure your dialog as shown. Use "Add Level" to add rows to the sort dialog:

[image]

2. You can sort by multiple columns using the sort feature in the Autofilter. To do this, you must sort each column one by one, in the opposite order to the sort columns shown in the image above. This is important. So first, you sort the year column. Then you sort the id column.

For both methods, the outcome is the same. The first method is simpler to see what's going on, but if you're comfortable, then the second method is fine.

Comment: Thank you so much! That worked perfectly and I learned something new :-)

Comment: Glad it helped. Please consider clicking the Accept answer button if your issue is resolved. If the answer was helpful, please consider upvoting the answer.